# Excel: Multi-way string search and extract

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column with 11k+ rows of text. Some of them look like this:

```
1. vc (abrev.), viscous coupling
```

and some may look like this:

```
2. manual transmission fluid, mtf (abrev.)
```

or even:

```
3. m/t (abrev.), manual transaxle, manual transmission, mt (abrev.)
```

My goal is simply extract "`* (abrev.)`" without the quotes from within the text, and place it in a new column. In the third case, it would be nice if both "`m/t (abrev.)`" and "`mt (abrev.)`" could be extracted and separated with a comma.

So far I've came up with this function

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("abrev.",C68),MID(C68,1,FIND(")",C68)),""),"")
```

which works in some cases, but not on everyone of them. (function was translated with http://en.excel-translator.de/translator/ because original function is in portuguese). I even tried using wildcards in the function but they don't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the maximum number of times that "abrev." can appear in one cell?  And you always want the character cluster (not necessarily a word) that precedes `(abrev)`, right?

Comment: 1. I believe two times is the maximum. 2. Exactly.

Comment: @pnuts, for the 1st example, column 1 would have viscous coupling, and column 2 of the same line would have vc (abrev.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for you but it takes multiple columns to do it.  If the data starts in cell A2, here are the formulas:

```
B2 = FIND("(abrev.)", A2)
C2 = IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(LEFT(A2,B2-1)),FIND(" ",TRIM(LEFT(A2,B2-1))))), "")
D2 = IFERROR(FIND("(abrev.)", A2, B2+1), "")
E2 = IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(LEFT(A2,D2-1)),FIND(" ",TRIM(LEFT(A2,D2-1))))), "")
F2 (your goal) = CONCATENATE(IF(LEN(C2) > 0, C2 & " (abrev.)", ""), IF(LEN(E2) > 0, ", " & E2 & " (abrev.)", ""))
```

Basically what it is doing is finding the phrase "(abrev.)" and then finding the space before the word before it and selecting that phrase and then putting them together again at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your help zgirod